# jq create an array with nested strcuture

Tags: jq

I have a file which holds several rows.
file:

```
row1
row2
```

For each row, I want to create the following, where the first set of reads are suffixed with "first", and the second is suffixed with "last"

```
[
  {
    "forward": "forward-row1-first",
    "reverse": "reverse-row1-first"
      },
  {
    "forward": "forward-row1-last",
    "reverse": "reverse-row1-last"
      }
]
```

Next, I would like to combine the above structure for each row in the file as the following:

```
[
  {
    "reads": [
      {
        "forward": "forward-row1-first",
        "reverse": "reverse-row1-first"
      },
      {
        "forward": "forward-row1-last",
        "reverse": "reverse-row1-last"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "reads": [
      {
        "forward": "forward-row2-first",
        "reverse": "reverse-row2-first"
      },
      {
        "forward": "forward-row2-last",
        "reverse": "reverse-row2-last"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have the following code:

```
create_json () {
  ROW="$1"

  for SUFFIX in 1 2; do
    FORWARD="forward-${ROW}_${SUFFIX}"
    REVERSE="reverse-${ROW}_${SUFFIX}"
    jq -n --arg forward "$FORWARD" --arg reverse "$REVERSE" '{forward: $forward, reverse: $reverse}'
  done | jq -n '.reads |= [inputs]'
}

DATA=()

while read -r line; do
    DATA+=($(create_json $line))
done < prefixes.txt

echo "${DATA[*]}"
```

The problem with this approach is that the json objects for each row from the file are appended to a bash array, and there for the output looks like:

```
{ "reads": [ { "forward": "forward-row1_first", "reverse": "reverse-row1_first" }, { "forward": "forward-row1_last", "reverse": "reverse-row1_last" } ] } { "reads": [ { "forward": "forward-row2_first", "reverse": "reverse-row2_first" }, { "forward": "forward-row2_last", "reverse": "reverse-row2_last" } ] }
```

How can I use jq in an elegant way to get the desired output format?

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? Are the rows suffixed as in the sample input? Or are they just automatically counted starting from 1?

Comment: @pmf I changed the description of the post. I think it should be clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the rows text file using the `-R` option. To iterate over the `inputs`, also use the `-n` option to start with the first line.

```bash
jq -Rn '
  reduce inputs as $row ([]; . += [{reads: [("first", "last") as $sfx | {
    forward: "forward-\($row)-\($sfx)",
    reverse: "reverse-\($row)-\($sfx)"
  }]}])
' rows.txt
```

```json
[
  {
    "reads": [
      {
        "forward": "forward-row1-first",
        "reverse": "reverse-row1-first"
      },
      {
        "forward": "forward-row1-last",
        "reverse": "reverse-row1-last"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "reads": [
      {
        "forward": "forward-row2-first",
        "reverse": "reverse-row2-first"
      },
      {
        "forward": "forward-row2-last",
        "reverse": "reverse-row2-last"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as clean as [@Pmf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75605276/5625547), but without `reduce()`, you could `map()` over the rows, and create the desired objects by looping over `[ "first, "last" ]` and create the object for each item:

```
jq -Rn '
    [ inputs ] 
        | map(. as $tmp 
        | { reads: [ ([ "first", "last" ] 
        | map({ forward: "forward-\($tmp)-\(.)", reverse: "reverse-\($tmp)-\(.)" })) 
    ] 
})'  input_file
```

```json
[
  {
    "reads": [
      [
        {
          "forward": "forward-row1-first",
          "reverse": "reverse-row1-first"
        },
        {
          "forward": "forward-row1-last",
          "reverse": "reverse-row1-last"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "reads": [
      [
        {
          "forward": "forward-row2-first",
          "reverse": "reverse-row2-first"
        },
        {
          "forward": "forward-row2-last",
          "reverse": "reverse-row2-last"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iJzY99Nei3j)